# Find time difference in minutes with php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two data inputs where you can enter start time and finish time.

for example

```
start_time 13:00

finish_time 14:40
```

The entry will be always the format of HH:MM.

I'd like to find the time difference, in this case 100 minutes.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What should happen if start_time > finish_time? Such as if start_time is just before midnight and finish_time right after

Comment: If the finish_time comes before the start_time, simply add a day to the finish_time and compute the difference between the Unix timestamps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) within [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime('13:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('14:40');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

$hours   = $interval->format('%h');
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');

echo $hours * 60 + $minutes;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use strtotime to get a timestamp from a string then get the difference from the timestamps, after that converting to a date or time formatted in minutes is easy.

Ex.

```
<?php
    $start = "26 Sep, 2010 13:00";
    $end = "26 Sep, 2010 14:40";

    $timeStart = strtotime($start);
    $timeEnd = strtotime($end);

    $diff = ($timeEnd - $timeStart);

    echo "Minutes : " . ($diff / 60) . "<br />";
    echo "Date : " . date("j M, Y h:i:s a", $diff); //This would end up being the
    //Years, months, days, hours, etc it took to complete the task.
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a function, so you can make this kind of calculation multiple times in a single script:

```
/**
 * get_time_difference
 *
 * @param   string  start time
 * @param   string  finish time
 * @return  int     time difference in minutes, rounded up
 */
function get_time_difference($start, $finish)
{
        return ceil(abs((strtotime($finish) - strtotime($start)) / 60));
}

$start_time = '13:00';
$finish_time = '14:40';

$diff = get_time_difference($start_time, $finish_time);
echo $diff; // 100
```

Note the use of the `ceil()` function (rounds up) to avoid any decimal answers.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about PHP - the time in PHP is represented as unixtime - number of seconds since epoch (1 Jan 1970). So you need to just substruct one time from another and you will get the difference in seconds.

If the time in php is in textual representation - you can convert it to unixtime by calling strtotime beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's assume that you have two strings in HH:MM format; `$time1` and `$time2` say. I'm going to assume that `$time1` and `$time2` refer to times on the same day in the same time zone (unless `$time1` is after `$time2`, in which case I'll assume that `$time2` is the day after `$time1`).

```
$time1 = explode(':', $time1);
$time2 = explode(':', $time2);
$time1_hours = intval($time1[0], 10);
$time1_mins  = intval($time1[1], 10);
$time2_hours = intval($time2[0], 10);
$time2_mins  = intval($time2[1], 10);
$time1_mins_past_midnight = 60 * $time1_hours + $time1_mins;
$time2_mins_past_midnight = 60 * $time2_hours + $time2_mins;
$time_difference = ( $time1_mins_past_midnight > $time2_mins_past_midnight ) ?
                   1440 + $time2_mins_past_midnight - $time1_mins_past_midnight :
                   $time2_mins_past_midnight - $time1_mins_past_midnight;
```

Now `$time_difference` contains the time difference, in minutes.