# PHP : How to calculate the remaining time in minutes?

Tags: php, time

Suppose the target time is 4.30 pm and the current time is 3.25 pm , how will i calculate the minutes remaining to reach the target time ? I need the result in minutes.

```
session_start();
$m=30;
//unset($_SESSION['starttime']);
if(!$_SESSION['starttime']){
   $_SESSION['starttime']=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
}
$stime=strtotime($_SESSION['starttime']);
$ttime=strtotime((date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime("+$m minutes"))));-->Here I want to calcuate the target time; the time is session + 30 minutes. How will i do that
echo round(abs($ttime-$stime)/60);
```

Krishnik

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Comment: strtotime("+30 minutes"); returns current time + 30 minutes. How can i pass time other than the current time to strtotime(); ?

Comment: take a look at the documentation, its right there http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php the second (optional) parameter is the timestamp from which it calculates

Comment: @Hannes Thanks i tried it earlier but did'nt work because i have passed wrong value, then i tried with a time stamp of the current time ... I think its working now. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick calculation of the difference between two times can be done like this:

```
  $start = strtotime("4:30");
  $stop = strtotime("6:30");
  $diff = ($stop - $start); //Diff in seconds
  echo $diff/3600; //Return 2 hours. Divide by something else to get in mins etc.
```

Edit*
Might as well add the answer to your problem too:

```
$start = strtotime("3:25");
$stop = strtotime("4:30");
$diff = ($stop - $start);
echo $diff/60; //Echoes 65 min
```

Oh and one more edit:) If the times are diffent dates, like start is 23:45 one day and end is 0:30 the next you need to add a date too to the strtotime.