# PHP Time Differences

Tags: php, time, minute

```
$myTime = "1311059513";
$now = time();
$timeDiff = ($now - $myTime)/60;
```

I'm trying to subtract `$myTime` from `$now` to get the difference and divide by 60 to get the minutes difference.
For some reason I don't get minutes in `$timeDiff`.

Comment: this has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: If you don't get minutes, what else do you get?  Since `$myTime` is a number and not text, don't use quotation marks; just write `$myTime = 1311059513;`.

Comment: Actually this is the time I get from the db and convert it to time with 'strtotime()'
2011-07-19 07:34:24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On: `PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 12 2011 18:36:55)`

I get:

```
$myTime = "1311059513";
$now = time();
$timeDiff = ($now - $myTime)/60;
echo $timeDiff; // 443.78333333333
```

What's the problem?

```
1311059513 corresponds to 2011-07-19T02:11:53-05:00
ran it at 2011-07-19T09:35:40-05:00

09:35:40 - 02:11:53 = 7hrs 23min 57s = 443min 57s = 443.7833...
```

Comment: Thanks! but how can I fix that?