# Calculate total hours between 2 time stamps

Tags: php, function

I have two variables:

```
$start_time = '9:36';
$end_time = '12:47';
```

How would i calculate the amount of hours between the two times and store them in a variable like this:

```
$total_hours = 3;
```

I have read that you need to convert the times first. Also there will be no need for date as this will all be on the same day.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please see strtotime and date http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php/365214#365214 but divide by 60*60 instead.

Comment: @bernie: This is a little different case - you do not have full timestamps, you only have strings representing hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves your problem:

```
$start = explode(':', $start_time);
$end = explode(':', $end_time);
$total_hours = $end[0] - $start[0] - ($end[1] < $start[1]);
```

See [this codepad](http://codepad.org/7gJkVj9M) for a proof.

This solution assumes both hours are from the same day.

Comment: Hi, i see how you used the explode function. It works. I subtracted the start date from the end date. the hours came out fine but it always miscalculated the minutes. Thank you

Comment: @SebastianOpperman: No problem. Just know that if start and end are on different dates, this solution will not work properly and you will have to adjust it. Good luck.

Comment: just stupid question, is 10 - (true) safe to assume it will always be same as (10 - 1)?

Comment: hi there @Tadeck, i tried your solution but it isn't really working i'm using 24 hour format and here's the result http://codepad.org/SxpWzo8A , but it doesn't even work with am/pm since maybe we aren't telling if its am/pm ? could you help it please ?

Answer (score 2):

if you only need to calculate the hours difference you could use the [datetime class](https://www.php.net/datetime) especifically the function [date_parse_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) where you just need to provide the format as seed and then what you need to parse give that calculate the difference

**Edit 1**

you could do something with less overhead:

```
$start_time = '9:36';
$end_time = '12:47';
$today = date('Y-d-m');
$start = strtotime($today . ' ' . $start_time);
$end = strtotime($today . ' ' . $end_time);

$diff = floor(($end - $start) / 3600);

// or if you don't need the exact hours

$diff = ($end - $start) / 3600;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert time string tor timestamp: `strftime`
2. Take the difference, and
3. a. Use `date` to get the hours (H) value
    
   b. Divide with 3600 and round as much digit as you
   need

`$total_hours = (int)date('G', abs(strtotime($time2)-strtotime($time1)));`

Comment: It works, except leaves zero in front of hour like that: "`03`". See [this codepad](http://codepad.org/EQSjrztD).

Comment: @Tadeck: To leave the leading zero, use `G` instead of `H` in `date`. `date('G', abs(strtotime($time2)-strtotime($time1)));`. And this works if more detailed times got as input, eg: `10:23:43 GMT`, as `strftime` could do the job

Comment: @netmano: So your solution should be rather `date('G', abs(strtotime($time2)-strtotime($time1)));`, not the one you have given. Or even this should be: `$total_hours = (int)date('G', abs(strtotime($time2)-strtotime($time1)));`, don't you think?

Comment: @Tadeck: yes, I missed the edit function, so I have written to commeny, btw, now I corrected in the answer. Thanks! And if you use the (int) casting, there is no problem of `H`, because 03 will be casted to 3 as int.

Comment: @netmano: Yes, in case of casting there is no difference in result. But to be consistent with different languages, having to chose between converting `03` and `3` to integer, I would choose the latter. In other languages ([such as eg. JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/xtsqb/)) the zero on the first position in numeric string matters.

Answer (score 1):

See below

```
$start_time = '9:36';
$end_time = '12:47';

$v =  strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time);
echo date("h:i", $v);
```

Outputs

```
 03:11
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Needs `date_default_timezone_set("UTC");` to avoid timezone issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you guys making it complicated? It can be done in a one-liner code:

```
abs((strtotime("11:00 AM") - strtotime("12:00 PM")) / 3600)
```

Result:

```
1
```

Please note that this assumes that both time are in the same day, although it will still work if both are from different dates.