# How to find out the days and minutes between 2 timestamps

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I am trying to find out the years, months, days and minutes between 2 timestamps.

I have used the following code, but it is not working:

```
$diff = time()-$res['asked_on'];
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
```

I am getting the output as:

0
0
0

$res['asked_on'] = 1331980897  ( It is also a time stamp getting from time() function )

Comment: What is not working? Is `$res['asked_on']` also the timestamp?

Comment: timestamp - says db to me, most db's would have functions for this, but you don't say what your using.

Comment: If the diff is less than 24 hours, you'll get 0 days, since 0.9999 days will floor out to 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If the `$res['asked_on']` is a string of date format, you should turn it to timestamp by using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

And if your php >= 5.3, you could take a look at the method php provide to you: [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)