# How to get the hour minute and second?

Tags: php

The future time is :`2012-05-26 00:00:00`

supposed there are three variable: `$hour  $minute $second`

now, i want to using the future time subtract now time. then give the left hour to `$hour`,give the left minute to `$minute`,give the left second to `$second`.

i am sorry i am new of php, now i get stucked how to do the math operation ? thank you

Comment: Read [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) or [use the search function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the math operations for the difference in hours,minutes and seconds

```
$future_datetime = '2012-05-26 00:00:00';
$future = strtotime($future_datetime); //future datetime in seconds
$now_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$now = date('U'); //now datetime in seconds

//The math for calculating the difference in hours, minutes and seconds
$difference = $future - $now;
$second = 1;
$minute = 60 * $second;
$hour = 60 * $minute;
$difference_hours = floor($difference/$hour);
$remainder = $difference - ($difference_hours * $hour);
$difference_minutes = floor($remainder/$minute);
$remainder = $remainder - ($difference_minutes * $minute);
$difference_seconds = $remainder;
echo "The difference between $future_datetime and $now_datetime is $difference_hours hours, $difference_minutes minutes and $difference_seconds seconds";
```

Comment: just for you to understand the concept easier :) 

you can just use `$minute = 60`

Answer (score 2):

A very good resource for dates and time..

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

-there are samples here doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [date_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function. There's the exact solution to what you're asking there.

And [here's the page (DateInterval::format)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) documenting how you can format the output.

```
$now = date_create();
// use "now" and necessary DateTimeZone in the arguments
$otherDate = date_create('2020-04-13');
$interval = date_diff($now, $futureDate);
echo $interval->format('%a days');
```