# How to get time in seconds from d-m-y h:i:s?

Tags: php, date, time, minute

I found this:

```
$minutes = (strtotime("2012-09-21 12:12:22") - time()) / 60;
```

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520145/number-of-minutes-between-two-dates/12520198)

But the string from the API that I took is like 06-09-19 | 16:23:17 and this code don't work at all.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: `(DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y \| H:i:s', '06-09-19 | 16:23:17')->format('U') - time()) / 60;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to manually parse that date format as it is non-standard using `DateTime::createFromFormat`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y \| H:i:s', '06-09-19 | 16:23:17');
$minutes =  ( $date->format('U')-time() ) / 60;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's do the trick!