# php process time to correct date and compare

Tags: php, com, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

i have been trying to get the time of a certain process but i want to compare it with the current time, i mean i want to get the total difference between when the process started, here at this blog : [php get process creation time](http://geeks-wiki.blogspot.com/2012/10/php-get-process-creation-time.html)

this guy has told the procedure to get the process timing, its working fine, but i am only stuck at comparing the time to current time!!

Is there any solution for this? or any alternative?

Comment: What you have tried ? paste some code ?

Comment: I think this question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: Agreed, more explanation is needed.

Comment: i am using the exact code that guy is providing there, but it gives only the time of that process's creation, i am trying this :

print $time - date('h:m:s'); 

as his code returns the $time as the time of that process's creation, shall i paste the full code here or what?

Comment: what does $pData from the guys code return? A timestamp? If so, compare it with time(). And see the linked dupe.

Comment: that question is related to something else, i just need to compare two different times and get the difference in hours minutes or even seconds :)

Comment: that is exactly what the linked dupe explains. there is a couple more questions about how to get time differences which you can easily find by searching (which is what you are supposed to do before asking questions).

Comment: $pDate is returning something like this: 20121005170307

Comment: But how is this 20121005170307 converted to the correct time?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
$msc=microtime(true);
$mysql_query($sql);
// or any process
$msc=microtime(true)-$msc;
```

Comment: I ain't using any SQL thing here?