# How to find time difference between 2 dates in php

Tags: php

I want to get the time difference between 2 dates in minutes. The 2 dates are in the following format

```
date1='05-11-2012 11:25:00'
date2='06-11-2012 17:45:00'
```

Comment: Refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('05-11-2012 11:25:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('06-11-2012 17:45:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); //return +1 days
//or
$datetime1 = date_create('05-11-2012 11:25:00');
$datetime2 = date_create('06-11-2012 17:45:00');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); //return +1 days
```

for php <5.3

```
$date1 = '05-11-2012 11:25:00';
$date2 = '06-11-2012 17:45:00';
$diff = floor(abs( strtotime( $date1 ) - strtotime( $date2 ) )/(60*60*24));
printf("%d days\n", $diff); //return 1 days
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

**For further reference please visit the following link**
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to indicate what format you'd like the time difference expressed in.  If you're willing to work in seconds (which are easily converted), you could simply convert each date to a timestamp and then take the absolute difference using basic math.  For instance, give $date1 = '05-11-2012 11:25:00' and $date2 = '06-11-2012 17:45:00':

```
$diff_seconds = abs( strtotime( $date1 ) - strtotime( $date2 ) );
```

And you could do whatever you like with the result.

Comment: More complex than date_diff, but maintains compatibility with PHP < 5.3.0.

Comment: Ha!  The last time I used PHP intensively was 5.2 -- I didn't even know date_diff existed!  A very useful alias.

Answer (score 0):

**$start_time = strtotime( "2012-10-12 11:35:00" );**

**$end_time = strtotime( "2012-10-13 12:42:50" );**

**echo round ( abs( $end_time - $start_time ) / 60,2 ). " minute";**

This is different between two dates in MINUTES.