# Getting time difference between two times in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

I am working on an attendance table to calculate the late and very late employees.
I am storing the login time in the table (Type: time).  I am able to get the time from the database and i would like to show the time difference in the separate column.

i.e., if employee logged on or before `09:00:59`, then its right time and the time diff should be shown as null.  If he logs in after the time i.e, `09:01:00` or later the time difference should be `00:00:01`.  Like wise i need to calculate the differences in time.

One time is constant i.e., `09:00:59` and another one i am getting from database table. Need to get diff between both.
I am working in PHP.
Hope my question is clear.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: search the stackof before posing your query

Comment: Yeah i searched well and i couldn't find for my requirement. thats i posted question. Thankyou.

Comment: @VallabhPatade . Its not duplicate question. That was another type of question

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for time calculation. Here is an example:

```
$checkTime = strtotime('09:00:59');
echo 'Check Time : '.date('H:i:s', $checkTime);
echo '<hr>';

$loginTime = strtotime('09:01:00');
$diff = $checkTime - $loginTime;
echo 'Login Time : '.date('H:i:s', $loginTime).'<br>';
echo ($diff < 0)? 'Late!' : 'Right time!'; echo '<br>';
echo 'Time diff in sec: '.abs($diff);

echo '<hr>';

$loginTime = strtotime('09:00:59');
$diff = $checkTime - $loginTime;
echo 'Login Time : '.date('H:i:s', $loginTime).'<br>';
echo ($diff < 0)? 'Late!' : 'Right time!';

echo '<hr>';

$loginTime = strtotime('09:00:00');
$diff = $checkTime - $loginTime;
echo 'Login Time : '.date('H:i:s', $loginTime).'<br>';
echo ($diff < 0)? 'Late!' : 'Right time!';
```

Check the already-asked question - [how to get time difference in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365214/1179841):

> Subtract the past-most one from the future-most one and divide by 60.
>
> Times are done in unix format so they're just a big number showing the
> number of seconds from January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: Thankyou ... its working cool.. The same thing i tried .  But i didn't get.  I dont know why.

Comment: Useless example. Check nonsence with this calculation (using your code): Time 1: 14:31:34
Time 2: 16:09:43
Diff: 02:38:09

Comment: This is not working in all cases: eg 12:15:00 and 12:15:01

Comment: To downvoters, thanks for down votes. I updated my example code.

Answer (score 26):

You can also use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)  class:

```
$time1 = new DateTime('09:00:59');
$time2 = new DateTime('09:01:00');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $interval->format('%s second(s)');
```

Result:

```
1 second(s)
```

Comment: it works.......

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
$start = strtotime("12:00");
$end = // Run query to get datetime value from db
$elapsed = $end - $start;
echo date("H:i", $elapsed);
?>
```