# Difference between two time values in php

Tags: php

I have two time values as follows

```
$start = '13:00:00';
$end = '21:00:00';
```

I want calculate the difference between these two time values, I want difference value in format like `00:00:00` (here result would be `08:00:00`)

I am using below code to calculate difference

```
$time = date( "h:i:s", strtotime($end) - strtotime($start));
```

but it gives me result as `01:30:00`

please help if anyone have any idea, i do not want to use `DateTime` class

> In my opinion it is not duplicate, if it is tell me the answer if your
>   can find in duplicate question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php

Answer (score 2):

```
   $datetime1 = new DateTime('13:00:00');
   $datetime2 = new DateTime('21:00:00');
   $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
   echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: The OP states he does not want to use DateTime class.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate this without using DateTime class?

Comment: The op said he didn't want to deal with dates. This doesn't force using dates

Comment: the only issue with `DateTime` is i'm getting this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()` may be because i might not have some libraries

Comment: And no, there isn't a way to do the above without using the class. Maybe thter are orher ways to get your value, but there isn't a secret other class that works just like DateTime class but has a name you like more

Comment: It means your version of php is out of date. 5.2 is no longer supported.

Comment: @Anthony actually there is very simple way, using just simple math, see the duplicate

Comment: Im sure there is. I meant there isn't a way to use my suggestion without the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code :

```
$time1 = strtotime('13:00:00');
$time2 = strtotime('21:00:00');
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
echo 'Difference: '.date('H:i:s', $diff);
```

Comment: getting 13:30:00 as a result :(

Comment: That's identical to the OPs code

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to do that with the [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php) function.

There is an example an that site.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: do i have mentioned i want days difference between two dates??

Comment: Manoj rather than that comment you could have tried to pass a time to this method :)