# how to get time difference between two time in php

Tags: php, time

I have two times. I want to get time difference between seconds, suppose there are two time time1 = 4:20 and time2 =20:10 now i want to get difference in seconds between them .

i do not have date parameters here ,please do not mark post as duplicate : [Getting time difference between two times in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php)

there there is day also , so my case is different

Comment: In what way is this different from the question you've included?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting time difference between two times in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php)

Comment: What do you mean by that? You have two times in the form of strings that you want to find the difference of. That's the same as the question marked as duplicate.

Comment: there is day also: where?

Answer (score 2):

```
$time1 = strtotime('01:30:00');
$time2 = strtotime('02:20:00');

$time_def = ($time2-$time1)/60;

echo 'Minutes:'.$time_def;
```

Answer (score 0):

If 4 in 4:20 is minutes and 20 is seconds:

```
function minutesAndSecondsToSeconds($minutesAndSeconds) {
    list($minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $minutesAndSeconds);
    return $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}

echo minutesAndSecondsToSeconds('20:10') - minutesAndSecondsToSeconds('4:20');
```

With hours:

```
function timeToSeconds($time) {
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time);
    return $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}

echo timeToSeconds('3:20:10') - timeToSeconds('1:20:00');
```

Or simply use strtotime that should works as explained here: [Getting time difference between two times in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php)

Comment: what ifi include hours also

Comment: If include hours, so your problem is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php so you can use strtotime or the same logic as in my answer, just add $hours in list and $hours * 3600 in result. it's some very basic algorythm you can easily adapt if you try to understand this function.

Answer (score 0):

This function will work for `MM:SS` and `HH:MM:SS` format:

```php
function TimeToSec($time) {
    $sec = 0;
    foreach (array_reverse(explode(':', $time)) as $k => $v) $sec += pow(60, $k) * $v;
    return $sec;
}
```

To calculate difference, use:

```php
echo TimeToSec('20:10') - TimeToSec('4:20');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/219285)</kbd>