# PHP difference between two times

Tags: php, date

I want to find the difference between two times. I have only time stored in database. I don't have date stored. 
Note : Time is in string format.

Case 1:

```
 Starting time : 06:18:09
 Ending time :  06:18:45
```

Case 2:

```
Starting time : 06:03:35    
Ending time 06:18:04
```

Case 3: [This case isn't working ]

```
Starting time : 23:44:56    
Ending time : 00:45:43
```

I'm using this code to find in seconds.But not working for me.

```
$datetime1 = date_create($a);
  $datetime2 = date_create($b);
  $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
 $min=$interval->format('%s');
```

Any helps ?

Thanks!

Comment: The solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php

Comment: Yes! I tried your method. But for this Starting time : 23:48:02 Ending time : 00:15:12 doesn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring at the first colon to remove the label, then use the remaining time stamp for parsing and subtracting.

Use PHP's `strtotime` method to convert the times as strings into longs, then subtract the two to find the difference in seconds. You'll have a number at this point, which you can then do whatever with.

```
$datetime1 = substr($datetime1, strpos($datetime1, ":"));
$time1 = strtotime($datetime1);
```

You can then use the `date` method to convert the time difference into a new string for outputting.

See:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Yes! I tried your method. But for this Starting time : 23:48:02  Ending time : 00:15:12  doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: It won't work because there is an overflow. Check if the second time is less than the first time, and if it is, add 24 hours worth of time to the second.

Comment: Yes. I also thought that to add 24 hours since second time is less than first. Again thank you so much sir!

Comment: subtracting 23:00 from 00:23 error