# DateInterval - Difference between two times

Tags: php, dateinterval

I have 2 times *(**DateInterval** - php)* and I would like to get the difference between them *(something like "diff()" function for DateTime)*.

My situation:

```
$task->estimate->format('%H:%I');          // HOURS:MINUTES / DateInterval 
$task->total_time->format('%H:%I');        // HOURS:MINUTES / DateInterval 
$task->total_time->diff($task->estimate);  // Not workin, only for DateTime
// difference between them?
```

It would be great without counting it in second, there must be easy way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP difference between two times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486600/php-difference-between-two-times)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @niceman Nope, date_diff doesn't work (date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, object given) and date_create() doesnt works too (not accepting normal nor formated dates of type DateInterval)

Comment: @JaredFarrish how to get difference between two values of type "DataInterval" (NOT DateTime)

Comment: diff of (now+interval1) and (now+interval2)

Comment: @splash58 how do you mean it? can you show php example?

Comment: If you can make your estimate and total time into total number of minutes (or seconds...), you can subtract the two total number of seconds and then turn that into a number of minutes and/or hours display.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate diif of (any time + interval1) and (the same time + interval2)

```
$estimate = new DateInterval('PT6H8M');
$total_time  = new DateInterval('PT5H7M');
$time = new DateTime('midnight');
$time->add($total_time);
$time1 = new DateTime('midnight');
$diff = $time1->add($estimate)->diff($time);
var_dump($diff); // object(DateInterval) ... ["h"]=> int(1) ["i"]=> int(1)  ...
```