# [PHP][MYSQL] how to do addition/subtraction on mysql's time datatype in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, operators

I have a couple of columns in my mysql table of datatype time.  The times are listed in military hours I believe, and i need get the difference(hours/mins) between the two times in PHP.  Example:

MYSQL:

```
Start_time  End_time
08:00:00    09:15:00
```

In php how can calculate (Start_time) - (End_time) = (result should be in mins).

Comment: Or you could use the `datediff()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it in mysql using this.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, column1, column2);
```

to get it in php see this answer

[Getting time difference between two times in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php)

Or use something like the following where you would use the dates you got from mysql as the strings to DateTime.

```
1 <?php
2   
3 $time1 = new DateTime('13:00:59');
4 $time2 = new DateTime('19:01:00');
5 $interval = $time1->diff($time2);
6 print_r($interval->format('%h:%s'));
```

To get the interval in a different format change the format string. You can find the valid string values in the [DateTime documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

To get minutes use "%i" or "%l", the latter has leading zeros.

```
1 <?php
2   
3 $time1 = new DateTime('13:00:59');
4 $time2 = new DateTime('19:01:00');
5 $interval = $time1->diff($time2);
6 print_r($interval->format('%l'));
```

Comment: In PHP be careful about times that go over 23:59:59.

Comment: Excellent!  TYVM.

Comment: How do i get it in minutes and not hours?

Comment: @dave I've updated the answer for minutes. I hope that helps. The docs contain everything you need.