# time difference between 2 values while if second value is past the current time

Tags: php

how to get the time difference between 2 values while **if second value is past the current time**?

i use below code:

```
function time_diff($date2, $date1, $format){

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  

$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));  

$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 -  $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24)); 

$hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24) / (60*60));  

$minutes = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24  - $hours*60*60)/ 60);  

$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minutes*60)); 


if ($format == 'year'){
 $i = $years;
}elseif ($format == 'month'){
 $i = $months;
}elseif ($format == 'day'){
 $i = $days;
}elseif ($format == 'hour'){
 $i = $hours;
}elseif ($format == 'minutes'){
 $i = $minutes;
}elseif ($format == 'second'){
 $i = $seconds;
}

return $i;

}
```

i want to get time difference between **(saved time in database)** and **(current time)**.

everything is fine, but when **(saved time in database) passes** and its **smaller than (current time)**, this code return value but without negative sign.

i mean if time difference is **2 day**, it return **2** while it should return **(-2)** or somethings like that cuz (saved time in database) passes and its smaller than (current time).

Comment: Why don't you use composer to parse the dates ?

Comment: You are making many false assumptions here. [Not every day has 24 hours. Not every year has 365 days. Most months don't have 30 days.](https://gist.github.com/thanatos/eee17100476a336a711e) Time computations always depend on a location (possibly an abstract one, such as UTC). Use [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: Try to read This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/finding-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates might also be relevant

Answer (score 0):

you used `$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));`, while `abs()` stands for absolute (as in the result is always positive) using `strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)` should work instead