# Calculate time different in minute and second

Tags: php, datetime

i try to compare 2 datetime and get the different in minutes and second and after i refer this topic [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php#answer-365220) yes that code can show the different but in minute:

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 18:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 18:41:58");

echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

so how to show in **minute and second** from above code? My php version is `5.2.17` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$minutes = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
$seconds = abs($to_time - $from_time) % 60;

echo "$minutes minute, $seconds seconds";
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively using the [DateTime class](http://php.net/datetime) for PHP >= 5.3:-

```
$to_time = new \DateTime('2008-12-13 18:42:00');
$from_time = new \DateTime('2008-12-13 18:41:58');
$diff = $from_time->diff($to_time);
echo $diff->format('%i Minutes %s Seconds');
```

Note: `$diff' will be an instance of [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval).

Or, slightly more concise, but less readable:-

```
$to_time = new \DateTime('2008-12-13 18:42:00');
$from_time = new \DateTime('2008-12-13 18:41:58');

echo $to_time->diff($from_time)->format('%i Minutes %s Seconds');
```