# PHP get time different in string

Tags: php, string, time, formatting

I have a time string, the first user's last login : '2014.12.01, 12:25'
And how to calculate the time different from now? For e.g. another user see the first user's last login

```
At 12:30 and it says 5 minute ago.
Or at 13:23 says 48 minute ago.
Or at 14:24 says 1 hour ago.
Or one day later, it says 1 day ago.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602474/67332)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting timestamp to time ago in PHP e.g 1 day ago, 2 days ago...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$to_time = strtotime("2014-12-01 12:25:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2014-12-01 12:25:00");

$minutes = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
$seconds = abs($to_time - $from_time) % 60;

echo "$minutes minute, $seconds seconds";
```

It had already been answered at the following link:

> ["Calculate time different in minute and second"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431624/calculate-time-different-in-minute-and-second)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$first_user_time = '2014-12-01 12:30:00';
$curnt_user_time = '2014-12-01 12:40:00';

$diff = date('h:i:s', strtotime($first_user_time)-strtotime($curnt_user_time))

echo $diff;

//it will give diff in hour : min : seconds
```