# PHP worker hours calculation

Tags: php, time, hour

So I have the program saving work start and end times into a database like so:

```
  id    worker_id                  start                     end
1351            7    2013-06-26 08:00:00     2013-06-26 17:00:00
```

It saves te times for each day separately, and what I need to do is get the working hours for a worker in a period of time set in a form, for example one month.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds simple, what have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Comment: I know the time difference part, what i don't get is how to calculate multiple entries simultaniously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) + [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) functions:

```
SELECT
    `worker_id`, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `start`, `end`)) as `total`
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    (`start` BETWEEN 'period-start-date' AND 'period-end-date')
    AND
    (`end` BETWEEN 'period-start-date' AND 'period-end-date')
GROUP BY
    `worker_id`;
```

Consider adding `WHERE` clause with constraining dates.

Comment: exactly what i needed, great job, thank you CORRUPT!