# CakePHP timehelper with most accuracy

Tags: cakephp, time, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to use CakePHP's [TimeHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::timeAgoInWords).

Let's say I have this date:  `Tue, 07 Jun 2011 10:53:31 GMT`

Its' epoch time is: `1307444011`

I need to get difference output with now, like this: `2 years, 24 days, 15 hours, 27 minutes and 43 seconds`

I tried this:

```
$userCreatedTimeStr = $this->Time->timeAgoInWords(
       1307444011, array(
        'end' => '+10 year',
        'accuracy' => array('second' => 'second')
    )
);
```

But this code gives `2 years ago`.

How can I fix this?

Edit: some test code is like this:
http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/cakephp/cakephp/source-class-CakeTimeTest.html#189-229

It seems like using core PHP functions is mandatory, rather than TimeHelper.

[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php/3923228#3923228)

[How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php/12382882#12382882)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting in the 'format' option to the options array?

E.g:

```
$userCreatedTimeStr = $this->Time->timeAgoInWords(
       1307444011, array(
        'end' => '+10 year',
        'format' => 'F jS, Y',
        'accuracy' => array('second' => 'second')
    )
);
```

EDIT: CakePHP limits the timeAgoInWords method like so:

> If the difference is one week or more, the lowest level of accuracy is day

Source: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeTime.html#_timeAgoInWords

I guess what you were trying to do simply isn't possible using this method, at least in version 2.3.

Comment: This gives 2 years, 3 weeks, 3 days ago

Comment: Yeah, it was just an example. I don't know the parameters for PHP time very well, but it gives an idea of what you need. If you wait a few minutes I can probably figure out exactly what to type.

Comment: Hmm, after testing, it doesn't seem to make much of a difference. Tried removing the 'format' option from my code and I get the same output... Seems strange to me...

Comment: Okay, I've been trying to get this working for ages! And just now came across this: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeTime.html#_timeAgoInWords
`NOTE: If the difference is one week or more, the lowest level of accuracy is day` So I guess that's why my answer is the closest you can get - probably going to have to use PHP's date function to get more accuracy. It seems weird to me that they'd limit it like this though...

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for your effort.