# Using Date time diff with timezones

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I found a link earlier regarding using time diffs and getting the difference in minutes, hours and days:
    [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

I was trying this:

```
    $date1 = new DateTime('first day of this month', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
    $date2 = new DateTime('first day of this month', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

    print_r($date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    print_r($date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

The output was like:

```
    2013-12-01 13:00:36
    2013-12-01 12:00:36
```

Then used this:

```
    $diff = $date2->diff($date1);
    print_r($diff);
```

But then i get 0 in all the differences. I want to get the difference between the two without using strtotime.. I is it outputing 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation doesn't make sense, since there is no difference. *2013-12-01 13:00:36 Amsterdam* and *2013-12-01 12:00:36 London* are the exact same point in time in human history. What you appear to expect is the offset difference between the London and Amsterdam timezones (i.e. GMT and GMT+1 differ by 1), but that has nothing to do with concrete timestamps.

Comment: Oh.. Yes.. I actually want to get the time offset .. But how do i get the difference between to timezones i have just declared and convert to minutes?

Comment: Just have a look at the DateTimeZone class documentation in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate the offset.Use [DateTimeZone::getOffset()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetimezone.getoffset.php)

```
$dateTimeZoneAmsterdam = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam");
$dateTimeZoneLondon = new DateTimeZone("Europe/London");


$dateTimeAmsterdam = new DateTime('first day of this month', $dateTimeZoneAmsterdam);
$dateTimeLondon = new DateTime('first day of this month', $dateTimeZoneLondon);


$timeOffset = $dateTimeZoneAmsterdam->getOffset($dateTimeLondon);

print_r($timeOffset); // 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Try DateTime::diff