# Simple php timer problems

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am making a php timer that i refresh with ajax every second on my page. But i am having problems getting it to work. I need it to countdown 8 minutes. This is the script

```
<?php
$saveTime = (3600*10); // Saved time from file/database
$thisTime = time(); // Current time
$diffTime = ($saveTime-$thisTime); // Difference in time
if($diffTime >= 1) {
    $countMin = floor($diffTime/60);
    $countSec = ($diffTime-($countMin*60));
    echo 'Time remaining until next run is in ',$countMin,' minute(s) ',$countSec,' seconds';
} else {
    echo 'Timer expired.';
}
?>
```

Comment: `But I am having problems getting it to work.` Please elaborate

Comment: It simply prints Timer expired. So the problem must be happening in the $diffTime variable. But I am not sure exactly what.

Comment: I think your time difference is not correct. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the value saved in the $saveTime variable.

`time()` returns the number of seconds since 1st January 1970. Your value for `$saveTime` is about 10am on that day.

You need to set $saveTime to some time in the future. For example,

```
$saveTime = time()+(8*60);  // 8 minutes into the future.
```