# I want to find difference between these two date with days,hours and minutes

Tags: php

I want to find difference between these two date with days,hours and minutes.

```
$date1 = "27-09-2014 05:00 AM";
$date2 = "29-09-2014 03:00 PM";
```

Comment: Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Don't worry I can help you, here is the link where you can tae help http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php read the last topic at the bottom of the page. Hope you will get help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

From PHP Version > 5 below new date/time functions added to get difference:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2010-06-20");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2011-06-22");
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo 'Difference: '.$difference->y.' years, ' 
                   .$difference->m.' months, ' 
                   .$difference->d.' days';

print_r($difference);
```

Result as below:

```
Difference: 1 years, 0 months, 2 days

DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 1
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 2
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 367
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('27-09-2014');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('29-09-2014');

$datetime1->setTime(05, 00);
$datetime2->setTime(15, 00);


$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%a Day and %h hours'
```

[DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php)