# PHP datetime: now - 2014-10-20 12:13:29

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get minutes between now and future time, please help me!

```
$time = now - future time  

echo minutes
```

Comment: We are sorry, we do not have telepathic abilities and are not able to read the minds of others. Try to explain in more details what you want from us.

Comment: If you want the difference in minutes between two dates, please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: i want to get time like this  structure:   now minus other datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateTime class to get desired result

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date = new DateTime("2014-10-20 12:13:29");

//calculate the difference between two dates
$diff = $now->diff($date);

//caculate number of minutes between two dates
$minutes = $diff->days * 24 * 60;
$minutes += $diff->h * 60;
$minutes += $diff->i;

// display difference in minutes
echo $minutes.' minutes';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Check this link for more information http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you are looking for the Datetime class check out this link:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

If you want the diffrence between times you'll need this:

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

Comment: pretty sure he's trying to get the difference in minutes between now and a future date

Comment: i think user is asking to use `DateTime` class and not `date()` function

Comment: Ah oke, then i missunderstood the question

Comment: @bruchowski you are true,thank you, i want to get difference in minutes beetween now and a future date.  Sorry for my english

Comment: @user3185208 I've editted the quetion. I think you need something like that