# How to prevent users from deleting a record from mysql within a certain time/date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a php/mysql statement which only allows users to delete a record at a certain date/time. Users can currently delete a record at anytime. However as it is a booking system, there should be 2 days notice whenever user wants to cancel a booking. Therefore i would like to know how to make a function which prevents users from cancelling a booking that is less than 2 days from the booking date/time.

My table currently has the following fields which are **BookingDate** and **Timeslot**.

Here is a snippet of code which currently does the mysql delete function.

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 $query1="DELETE from bookings1 where booking_id='$id'";

 $results = $mysqli->query($query1);
```

What I would like to do is to validate this delete function to prevent users from deleting records that is less than 48 hours of the booking date ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: how would this help with my question ?

Comment: The easiest way of doing this would be to convert your datetime fields into minutes, calculate the difference and then convert them back.  You could then use your php code to limit it.

Comment: will you be able to show me an example

Answer (score 0):

In general, I advocate developing an API for applications.  That means that the application speaks to the database using stored procedures and views, rather than directly using SQL queries.

A primary reason for this is that additional logic can be implemented in the stored procedures.  So, if you had a `usp_delete_booking` stored procedure, then the logic could be implemented there, returning a nice error message when called.

The alternative is to implement a trigger that does the testing.  This gets complicated when you start introducing more advanced permissions -- so a user can't normally delete a booking two days before.  But a supervisor can.  Or, under certain circumstances, you might allow it.  The trigger will have to implement all the logic, because it is hard to circumvent.