# Convert Date & Time in UTC time Format and store into database in php

Tags: javascript, php, utc

Convert Date & Time in UTC time Format and store into database in php. Means Auction End Date time store in UTC Formate in the database.

When display data before come to client side in the controller Take current UTC time for server and Make different between Auction End time and Current UTC Time

Comment: UTC isn't a format, it's a standard and a timezone. What format do you actually want?

Comment: What code did you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)