# Finding amount of overlapping minutes in two PHP DatePeriods

Tags: php, datetime, overlap

I want to find the amount of overlapping minutes given two [DatePeriods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

For example,

- I have $startDate1 and $endDate1 as the first date range.
- I have $startDate2 and $endDate2 as the second date range.

(For demonstration sake, the format is 'Y-m-d H:i'. )

- Suppose $startDate1 = '2015-09-11 09:15' and $endDate1 = '2015-09-13 11:30'.
- Suppose  $startDate2 = '2015-09-13 10:45' and  $endDate2 = '2015-09-14 12:00'.

I expect a result of 45 minutes overlap. How can this be achieved?

> This question was marked as duplicate but they are not the same. I'm looking for the amount of **overlapping** time in two **DatePeriods** not the difference between two dates. A "DatePeriod" consists of two dates and I'm looking for the amount of **overlap** (not difference) between two DatePeriods.

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: This does not answer my question. The example you gave me was not using two date periods it was only using two dates. A date period consists of two dates.

Comment: Also, I'm not looking for the difference, I'm looking for the amount of overlapping time.

Comment: @LukeJames surely you could use the answers in the linked topic to formulate your own solution using some logic e.g. if endDate1 > startDate2 then get the diff of them

Answer (score 0):

Here is class **DatePeriodsOverlap**, which represent overlap of two periods.
It's result is overlapping **DatePeriod** or **Exception** if there is no intersection.

Note: DatePeriod is traversable object, PT1M is duration of step to iterate. **PT1M** means one minute interval. Details [about DateInterval](http://php.net/DateInterval) object.

Example of usage and answer to the question, how to get overlapping in minutes:

```
<?php
$d1 = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2015-09-11 09:15:00'),
    new DateInterval('PT1M'),
    new DateTime('2015-09-13 11:30:00')
);


$d2 = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2015-09-13 10:45:00'), 
    new DateInterval('PT1M'),
    new DateTime('2015-09-14 12:00:00')
);

$overlapPeriod = (new DatePeriodsOverlap(
    $d1, 
    $d2, 
    new DateInterval('PT1M')) // PT1M - 1 minute interval, 
                              // P1D - 1 day interval
)->overlap();


$minutes = iterator_count($overlapPeriod); // 45 minutes

// interval in minutes without iterating
$overlapPeriod->getEndDate()
    ->diff($overlapPeriod->getStartDate())
    ->i; // is interval in minutes (H:i:s)


/**
 * Overlap of two periods
 */
class DatePeriodsOverlap {
  private $d1;
  private $d2;
  private $di; // DateInterval, default is 1 day

  /**
   * @param DatePeriod $d1 first period
   * @param DatePeriod $d2 second period
   * @param DateInterval $di interval measurement
   */
  public function __construct(
    DatePeriod $d1, 
    DatePeriod $d2, 
    DateInterval $di = null) 
  {
    $this->d1 = $d1;
    $this->d2 = $d2;
    $this->di = $di ?? new DateInterval('P1D');
  }

  /**
   * Returns new overlapping period
   *
   * @throws Exception if not overlapped
   * @return DatePeriod 
   */
  public function overlap() : DatePeriod 
  {
    $startOne = $this->d1->getStartDate();
    $endOne = $this->d1->getEndDate();

    $startTwo = $this->d2->getStartDate();
    $endTwo = $this->d2->getEndDate();

    //If the dates overlap
    if ($startOne < $endTwo && $endOne > $startTwo) 
    {
      return new DatePeriod(
        max($startTwo,$startOne), 
        $this->di,
        min($endOne,$endTwo)
      );
    }

    throw new Exception(
      "No overlap " .
      "[{$this->d1->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}-{$this->d1->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}] and " .
      "[{$this->d2->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}-{$this->d2->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]"
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also provide a short explanation for you suggested solution

Comment: @yakobom Thank you for review, I've updated the answer with details.