# total login time on website displaying a wrong time

Tags: php, mysql

Hy !
I have 3 variables in database login_time, logout_time, total_time.
The datatype of total_time is 'time' while the other two have 'date_time' datatype.
What i did, I extract only login_time and logout_time in query and saved them into variables.
I have login and logout time stored in variables. Now i need to calculate total time in Hours, min, second.
I tried to calculate but it does not give exact time like this.

login_time = 2016-03-21 14:09:28

logout_time = 2016-03-21 14:10:22

total_time = 11:50:32

That's wrong !
What's my mistake ?

I tried many solutions but they did not resolved my problem !
Help me

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['start_time']))
{
    $start = $_SESSION['start_time'];
    $final = $_SESSION['final_time'];
    $diff = strtotime($final) - strtotime($start);

     //"%H:%M:%S"
    $total = date('H:i:s', $diff);
    $sql4 = "UPDATE log SET total_time = '$total' WHERE username = '$user'";
  $res4 = mysqli_query($link, $sql4);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `DateTime.diff` method like:

```
$start = new DateTime('2016-03-21 14:09:28');
$final = new DateTime('2016-03-21 14:10:22');
$diff = $final->diff($start);

var_dump($diff->format('%H:%I:%S'));
```

The result would be:

```
string(8) "00:00:54"
```

Comment: @Matei Mihai
Error : Call to a member function diff() on a non-object on line 61.
line 61: $diff = $final->diff($start);
Where the $start comes from these lines .
  $start = $_SESSION['start_time'];
   $start_time = new DateTime($start);

Comment: This is strange.. make sure your both `$start` and `$final` variables are `DateTime` objects

Comment: @MateiMihai
Yeah ! i have rechecked again.

Comment: var_dump both $_SESSION variables to see what's their values

Comment: what version of PHP do you use?

Comment: @MateiMihai
oh sorry, that was a little mistake by me.
now i am getting the time but still there lies a difference.
see the output .
login_time: 2016-03-21 14:53:52,,,
logout_time:2016-03-21 14:54:27,,
total_time:00:00:35.......that is strange !!
...........The total_time must be 00:01:25........

Comment: @MateiMihai
Sorry?
What do you mean by "do the math backord" ?

Comment: The result 0.0.37 is correct.. you should do the math again to see it's right

Comment: @MateiMihai
what should be the result of 54:27  -   53:52   ?..... 0:37 or 1:35 ...?????

Comment: 00:00:35 :) 27 seconds + 8 seconds. . That's all

Comment: @MateiMihai
Yeah !
Thanks .
God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this?

```
$difference = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
$query = "UPDATE log SET total_time = '$difference' WHERE username = '$user'";
if($link->query($query)):
    echo 'Success';
endif;
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php).

> Note, this code looks like there is an SQLi injection present, ensure you're *stripping* the `$user` variable of HTML before inserting it into the database if it came from an **un-trusted** user input source.

Comment: Have you converted it to a Data Type DateTime? Try that, hope it helps. Or use: `strtotime($to_time)` and the same to the `$from_time`