# php how to subtract or add dates?

Tags: php, sql, date

So I want to get our current date today (m-d-Y) then add 30 days. I would put this in a mySQL database.  Then each day it will say how many days left when it is close to 14 days.

```
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$expireDay = date('m-d-Y', strtotime("+30 days"));
$timeToEnd = $expireDay - $today;
if ($timeToEnd <= strtotime("$expireDay - 14 days")// this is not correct syntax
{
echo "less than 14 days";
echo $timeToEnd('d')//here is where I am having problems with my syntax
} else {
echo "more than 14 days";
}
```

Comment: `$expireDay` is a string, not an integer. If you use `strtotime` you can run math on it to get the data. Also `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` can just be `time()`.

Comment: This question is being asked almost every second day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `$today` is just for testing if that is the case this code should work. Your code was trying to subtract a string which you can't do. `date('m-d-Y', strtotime("+30 days"));` is a date string `03-27-2016`, to subtract you need an integer which `strtotime` will give.

```
$today = time();
$expireDay = strtotime("+30 days");
$daysleft = (($expireDay - $today) / 86400);
if ($daysleft <= 14 ) {
     echo "less than 14 days";
     echo $daysleft;
} else {
     echo "more than 14 days";
}
```

Comment: I have been spending all day on this.  Thanks a bunch! :)