# Time Difference from current time and sql table retrieved time

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve a time from Mysql table and want to get it's difference with current time time.

To be More clear :

[Current_Time]-[Time retrieved from SQL TABLE] = HH:MM:SS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Comment: [The MySQL answer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: and you've tried what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the calculation in the database.  For instance, if the "time column" is stored as `datetime`:

```
select timediff(now(), t.timecol)
from table
```

If the `timecol` is stored as a `time` data type, then use:

```
select timediff(curtime(), t.timecol)
from table
```

Comment: how to echo the results ?? @gordon linoff ?