# Check a date interval with strtotime in php

Tags: php, strtotime

I need a little help with this code:

```
$key['time_stamp'] = '2016-09-02 16:56:25';
$datetime1 = strtotime(date($key['time_stamp']));
$datetime2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:m:s'));
$interval = $datetime2 - $datetime1;
$val = 45 * 60 * 1000;

if ($interval > $val) { }
```

My purpose is to check if the `$interval` between two dates is greater than 45 mins.

`$key['time_stamp']` is `2016-09-02 16:56:25` and `datetime2` is the current date time. Why the `if` condition is never true?!

Did I miss something stupid or what?!

Comment: Unless I'm blind, you're missing something totally important: You need to tell people which programming language you're talking about! I'm guessing this is about perl, and added a tag to that effect. If I was wrong, please clarify or correct or something!

Comment: right,  I'm using php :)

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php ?

Comment: yes I already tried whit that solution

Comment: I've broken down and bungled my way through writing what I think should be a workable solution. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find working with [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects easier to reason about, and they are transparently comparable in an `if` statement.

I'd like to suggest an alternative approach:

```
<?php

$key['time_stamp'] = '2016-09-02 16:56:25';

$then = new DateTime($key['time_stamp']);
$interval = new DateTime('-45 minutes');

if ($then < $interval) {
    echo 'interval passed';
} else {
    echo 'interval not passed';
}
```

This yields:

> interval passed

Hope this helps :)

One caveat that's not applicable in your case but it's worth mentioning: If you create a `DateTime()` object with a UNIX timestamp using [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) be sure to check that both `DateTime()` objects have the same timezone.

Comment: I've done a quick check and it seems to work fine, I love you so much, tnx :)))

Comment: Great. No problema :)

Answer (score 2):

If $key['time_stamp'] is '2016-09-02 16:56:25', shouldn't it be

```
$datetime1  = strtotime ( $key['time_stamp'] );
```

Instead of

```
$datetime1  = strtotime ( date ($key['time_stamp']) );
```

?

Comment: I think so, and I think he shouldn't be trying to convert the system time, as it's already in millisecond form.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$val = 45*60*1000;
```

gives 45 minutes in millisecond, I guess you want:

```
$val = 45*60;
```

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes:

1. the minutes in the `$format` parameter of the [`date` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) have to be expressed as `i` (and not `m`, as you did).
2. `$interval` is measured in seconds (so you don't have to multiply by 1000, as if they were milliseconds).

So your code should be written as follows:

```
$key['time_stamp'] = '2016-09-02 16:56:25';
$datetime1 = strtotime(date($key['time_stamp']));
$datetime2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$interval = $datetime2 - $datetime1;
$val = 45 * 60;

if ($interval > $val) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your query.

```
$key['time_stamp'] = "2016-09-02 16:56:25";
   $datetime1 = strtotime ( date ($key['time_stamp']) );
   $datetime2  = strtotime ( date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

   $interval   = round(($datetime2 - $datetime1)/ 60); //interval in minutes

   $val = 45; //45 minutes
   if ($interval > $val) {
     echo "Success";
   }
```