# How to calculate the hours and mins between 2 time;

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

How do I count the hours and mins between the 2 time,
like for example:

`between 9:00 and 6:20`

I want to count the time from in to out.
what should be retrieve is 9:20.

I am using codeigniter for these;

```
$in = date('h:i',strtotime("09:00:00"));
$out = date('h:i',strtotime("06:20:00"));
```

Comment: [`date_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) might help ..

Comment: Difference between 9:00 and 6:20 is 2 Hours and 40 Min, Not 9:20

Comment: no, i want to count the time from in to out,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this problem first you need to convert 6.20 to 18:20. Use the code below

```
$in = '9:00';
$out = '6:20';
$new_out=date('H:i:s',strtotime($out.'+ 12 hours'));
```

Now, the new value of the *out* time is 18:20.

To find the difference between two times, use the following code

```
$formated_in = new DateTime($in);
$formated_new_out = new DateTime($new_out);
$dteDiff  = $formated_in->diff($formated_new_out);
echo $dteDiff->format("%H:%I");
```

The output is 09:20

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
echo dateDifference('09:00:00','06:20:00');


function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%h %i' )
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

from here

[How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

Comment: i wanted to count the time from in to out sir,