# Php get difference of a Time in H:i:s format

Tags: php, string, time, format, difference

How can I get the difference of a time.

Let's say the first time value is this:

```
00:01:00
```

and the second one is this:

```
00:03:00
```

How can I get the difference with the same format.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date-diff.php

Comment: checkout this : [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
    $startTime = new DateTime("00:01:00");
    $endTime = new DateTime("00:03:00");

    $interval = $startTime->diff($endTime);
    echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Outputs:

```
00:02:00
```

As you asked you wants it to be in same format.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this its work for me

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

u can also do this

```
<?php
$date1 = time();
sleep(2000);
$date2 = time();
$mins = ($date2 - $date1) / 60;
echo $mins;
?>
```

Comment: If you are using other answers on SO to post all or part of your answer, please add reference to the original answer!