# Time Difference in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, date, time, timestamp

Check the Time Difference in Symfony

i am comparing 2 Times. checking time difference is 4 Hours or Grater ot not.?

```
$createdAt =  $getCreatedAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$convertCreatedTime = strtotime($createdAt.' + 4 hour');
$createdTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$convertCreatedTime);
$todayTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo $createdTime."<br />"; //2017-02-21 04:00:53

echo $todayTime."<br />"; //2017-02-21 17:32:26

if($todayTime >= $createdTime){ // Check the createdTime 4 Hours Older that Now
    // Yes Older
}else{
    // No Not Older
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pls use `DateTime()` and `modify()` function to modify the date.

```
<?php
    $createdAt =  $getCreatedAt; // Created Date
    $createdAt->modify("+4 Hours"); // +4 Hours
    $todayTime = new \DateTime(); // Current Date

    if($todayTime >= $createdAt){ // Check the createdAt 4 Hours Older that Now
        // Yes Older
    }else{
        // No Not Older
    }
```

**#1**

Only additional info. Not related to question directly.
Use `diff()` function to get difference between two dates.

```
$dayDiff = $todayTime->diff($createdAt);
var_dump($dayDiff);
```