# Time difference is not working in some cases

Tags: php, time

I am using this code to generate time difference

```
$to_time = strtotime("2017-03-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2017-03-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

It was working fine but when my from_time is **23:44:00** and to time is **00:44:00** I am getting time difference **-1380 minute**.

Please help me on this.

Reference article of stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365220/1780414)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code , replace - with before

Comment: working fine:-  https://eval.in/752519

Comment: Thanks @AlivetoDie

Comment: @AlivetoDie what happened I am taking only time to calculate difference but when from time is 23:44:00 date will be same and to time is 00:44:00 the date will be changed to next day. I am passing the previous date only that's why I am getting wrong difference. Now I got it after your explanation. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:-

It seems that You are calculating difference only on the basis of time.

But when date will also consider then problem will not occur because 23:44:00 will be considered as next date with 00:44:00 time (automatically by php strtotime) and calculation will be accurate.

Check here:-https://eval.in/752519

Comment: glad to help you:)