# How to format DateInterval results

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have a task module, in it I have two fields

- t_due_on(task complete date)
- t_completed_on (task completed date)

Example data:

```
id        task_name   t_due_on                      t_completed_on   
1         PF Module   2017-03-14 10:15 PM           2017-03-13 23:29 PM
```

The given task's due date is tomorrow but it was actually finished today, so I need to display the results like:

```
Task finished: 1 day before
```

Comment: Look at similar questions like this and just adapt it for what you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DateTime::diff()` or `DateTimeImmutable::diff()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). All you have to do is to compare the two dates. I have given a very basic example here:

```
$dt1 = new DateTimeImmutable('2017-03-14 00:00:00');
$dt2 = new DateTimeImmutable('2017-03-16 12:00:00');

$di = $dt2->diff($dt1);
$outputStr = "Task finished: {$di->days} days ";
$suffix = $di->invert == 1 ? 'before' : 'after';
$outputStr .= $suffix . " deadline";

echo $outputStr;
```

Now it is important to note that:

- the `diff()` function will produce a [DateInterval class instance](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). This does not provide methods but rather explains the time interval in terms of seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks etc.
- notice that `$di->invert` is high (== 1) when the interval is `-2 days` for eg. `$di->invert` will be 0 for positive differences
- the order of comparison is important! So calling `$dt2->diff($dt1)` is not the same as `$dt1->diff($dt2)` because of how the dates are spaced in time
- you have to take care of the output. I.e. IF the difference between the two dates is less than a day `$di->days` will be 0! But `$di->h` will be set. Thus your functionality has to intelligently handle this also