# php get time difference between current time and specific time

Tags: php, date, time

i want to find time difference in minutes between current time and specific time.
for example,current time is '02:00:00' am and the specific time is '22:00:00'pm.
From my code below i get some negative number, i should get 240 minutes time difference.

```
$difference=strtotime('02:00:00') - strtotime('22:00:00');
 echo $difference/60;
```

I get -1200

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Comment: But the difference is 20 hours, and that is 1200 minutes.

Comment: if negative, add 24*60 minutes