# Time difference in php (h:m:s) format

Tags: php, date, time

I am insert a two time in database and how to find the difference to two times the result is show like h:s:m format  i will try to find the difference of this time

```
$from_time = $worker->timefm; //08:30:00  
$to_time= $worker->timeto;  //17:00:00
$diff=$to_time-$from_time;
echo $diff; //9
```

The answer show 9 only ,the correct answer is 8:30 why this show only 9 how the answer show in time format how to solve this issue ? help me!! thanks in advance

i will try this codes

> [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

but not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm using `date()` function. Before calling this this function, I'm making the default time zone to UTC using `date_default_timezone_set()`.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$diff= strtotime($to_time) - strtotime($from_time);
echo date('H:i:s', $diff);

OUTPUT
08:30:00
```

Comment: Won't you have a problem if the difference is greater than 24 hours?

Comment: You need to return full date and time not only time in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to calculate the time difference it will also work with the date and time data.
It works simply by getting difference in seconds and then converting it into h:m:s format.

```
function get_time_difference($t1, $t2)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($t1);
    $t2 = strtotime($t2);;
    $hour = floor(($t1-$t2)/3600);
    $minute =floor(($t1-$t2)/60)%60;
    $second = ($t1-$t2)-($hour*3600+$minute*60); 
    return (date("H:i:s",strtotime($hour.":".$minute.":".$second)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

// Time Calculation
$datetime1 = new DateTime('13:40:50');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('15:45:57');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%M:%S time');

?>
```

Just run this code and you will get the time difference in H:M:S  format
like this
02:00:07 time