# How do i get the bigger timing stored in the database to deduct the smaller one

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a database that stores the time when a form is submitted.
There are two forms thus 2 different timings are stored.
How do I automatically get the bigger time to minus the smaller time and display the results.

> Things I've tried:  (a part of index.php)

```
$timeR = 'timeR';
$timeB = 'timeB';
if ($timeR > $timeB) {
    echo ( strtotime($timeR) - strtotime($timeB) );
}
else{
    echo ( strtotime($timeB) - strtotime($timeR) );
}
```

`timeR` and `timeB` is the row name that is used to store the time.
The code above doesn't work, no errors but nothing is printing.

```
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo ( strtotime($row1['timeB']) - strtotime($row['timeR']) );
```

This code above works and prints something but the numbers printed are wrong??

Time is stored using another page that inserts data into the database which then redirects you to `index.php`

Time is stored like this on insertblue.php:

```
$currenttimeB = date('Y-m-d - H:i:s');
echo $sql="UPDATE indextableblueupdated SET FTPBreach = '$_POST[FTPBreach]', 
                                        VictimIP = '$_POST[VictimIP]', 
                                        VictimPass = '$_POST[VictimPass]', 
                                        SQLUser = '$_POST[SQLUser]', 
                                        SQLPass = '$_POST[SQLPass]', 
                                        message = '$_POST[message]', 
                                        timeB = '$currenttimeB' WHERE user = '2'" ;
```

Similarly I have another page called `insertred.php` which does the exact same thing as `insertblue.php`

Comment: I've read that post and honestly i have no idea what's going on. Am pretty new to php / hmtl. @faintsignal Also i do not have issue with posting to database but rather am trying to find out how can i retrieve and do calculations between 2 timings from a database.

Comment: Tried something else and edited post to match current situation

Comment: Never directly use `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables in SQL statement, it might lead to SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: @Raptor I'm running this on a local network designed to allow "students" to learn how sql injection work. I'm also a student just that i'm a third year and i'm suppose to design a "game" for my juniors. Its a project.

Comment: There are several improvements you can perform: *1.* You can do the time difference calculations in the MySQL server using `DATEDIFF()` and then `UPDATE` using the same query. In this way, you don't need to maintain multiple scripts; *2.* For the date format, I hope you didn't save the dates using `VARCHAR` data type, you should save it as `DATETIME`; *3.* avoid using `strtotime()` without checking the result (whether it's a valid date or not).

Comment: @Raptor hi, i saved the time as TIME, should i replace strtotime() with something else?

Comment: You cannot fit the value of `date('Y-m-d - H:i:s')` into `TIME` column. Change the data type and re-insert all the data

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert timeR  and timeB to time before comparing:

```
$timeR = strtotime($row1['timeR']); //assuming this from your table
$timeB = strtotime($row1['timeB']); //assuming this from your table
if ($timeR > $timeB) {
    echo ( $timeR - timeB );
}
else{
    echo ( $timeB - $timeR );
}
```