# PHP DateTime diff returning incorrect value in minutes

Tags: php

I have this PHP code which calculates the time between 2 timestamps and displays it in minutes...

```
$timestamp1 = new DateTime();
$timestamp1->setTimestamp('1540718680');

$timestamp2 = new DateTime();
$timestamp2->setTimestamp('1540747360');

$since_start = $timestamp1->diff($timestamp2);

echo $since_start->i.' minutes<br>';
```

For some reason it is returning 58 minutes insead of 477 minutes.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: DateInterval gives you formatted difference. Try: `$since_start->format('%h:%i')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%i` gives only the minutes, it's like asking for the 10s digit in a 3 digit number.  You also need the hours since minutes is just the remainder after the larger units are subtracted.

You could also do the computation yourself, `b-a/60`, to get the number of minutes between the two specified timestamps.