# PHP - Difference between Time in Minutes

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate the difference of two times. I'm using this method to return the difference in minutes.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('9.00am');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('10.15am');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$timeDuration = $interval->format('%im');
```

However, the `$timeDuration` returns `15m` instead of `75m`.
Any help that could correct the code to let it return the exact correct difference in minutes ?

Comment: Have you checked whether the inputed dates were parsed properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Because the [difference](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) between `9am` and `10:15am` is 1 hour (`$interval->h`) and 15 minutes (`$interval->i`), not 75 minutes literally.

If you wish to get the total number of minutes, you have to calculate it:

```
$differenceInMinutes = $interval->i + ($interval->h * 60);
```

If you wish to have more universal solution, I would go for the unix time:

```
$differenceInSeconds = abs($datetime1->format('U') - $datetime2->format('U'));

$differenceInMinutes = ceil($differenceInSeconds / 60);
```

Comment: If it wiil be more than 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to get different in minutes

```
<?php

 $start = date_create('1990-01-01 09:00:00');
 $end = date_create('1990-01-01 10:15:00');

 $interval=date_diff($end, $start);

 $hours   = $interval->format('%h'); 
 $minutes = $interval->format('%i');

 $in_minutes = $hours * 60 + $minutes;

 echo  'Diff. in minutes is: '.$in_minutes;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to calculate the difference between two `DateTime`'s like `$datetime1 = new DateTime('9.00am');` and `$datetime2 = new DateTime('10.15am');` you know that the difference is 75 minutes, but the resulto of `diff()` method is 1 hour for `$interval->h` and 15 minutes for `$interval->i`. So this is how you can calculate it:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('9.00am');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('10.15am');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$hours   = $interval->format('%h'); 
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
$difference_in_minutes = $hours * 60 + $minutes;

echo  'Difference in minutes is: ' . $difference_in_minutes . "\n";
```

There a working [snipped in this link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b2a25dbd47dea87a7f650d7fe6a7fda9e1e6a79)