# PHP: Count the past hours / days

Tags: php, timestamp

I've a timestamp in this format here: `2019-05-21 19:57:21`
Now I want to display the hours / days that are past from this timestamp.

For example when the timestamp is older than 2 minutes, I want to print `2 minutes` until it reached `59 minutes`.

From know on it must be hours. So for example after `59 hours` it should be `1 hour`.

After reaching `24 hours`, it should say `1 day`, `2 days`. After one week, it should print `1 week` (we'll let the years out).

This is what I've done by myself. I'm don't know how I can complete this:

```
$timestamp = '2019-05-21 19:57:21';

function calculate_notification_time( $notification_time ) {

    $now  = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
    $past = new DateTime( $notification_time );
    $dt   = $now->diff( $past );

    error_log( print_r( $now, true ) );

    if ( $dt->y > 0 ) {
        $number = $dt->y;
        $unit   = 'Jahr';
    } else if ( $dt->m > 0 ) {
        $number = $dt->m;
        $unit   = 'Monat';
    } else if ( $dt->d > 0 ) {
        $number = $dt->d;
        $unit   = 'Tag';
    } else if ( $dt->h > 0 ) {
        $number = $dt->h;
        $unit   = 'Stunde';
    } else if ( $dt->i > 0 ) {
        $number = $dt->i;
        $unit   = 'Minute';
    } else if ( $dt->s > 0 ) {
        $number = $dt->s;
        $unit   = 'einigen Sekunden';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $unit ) && ! empty( $number ) && $number > 1 ) {

        switch ( $unit ) {
            case 'Jahr':
                $unit .= 'en';
                break;
            case 'Monat':
                $unit .= 'en';
                break;
            case 'Tag':
                $unit .= 'en';
                break;
            case 'Stunde':
                $unit .= 'n';
                break;
            case 'Minute':
                $unit .= 'n';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return $number . ' ' . $unit;
    }

    return 'Zeit nicht Verfügbar';
}
```

**UPDATE:**

With the help of an answer I've figured this out. The strange thing is that the minutes are totally wrong and going backwards. So 20 minutes ago it was 35 minutes and now its 15 minutes. So strange....

Comment: See [DateTime::diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky can you check my updated answer? This would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp = '2019-05-21 11:49:21';
$unixTimestampS = strtotime($timestamp);
$dNow =  strtotime("now");
$diff = $dNow- $unixTimestampS;
if($diff <60) {
    $result =  $diff. ' seconds ago'; // When it's not 1 minute
} elseif (($dNow- $unixTimestampS) > 60 && ($dNow- $unixTimestampS) < 3600) {
    $result = $diff . ' minute ago'; // For example: 19 minutes
}
echo $result;
```

or a better approach is mentioned here
[How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you take a look at it?