# How to get minute from two date diffrence in php?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have some DateTime like this `2019-10-04 07:58:00`, I need the difference between the two date to be returned in minutes.

```
$current = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$date    = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($old_date)));
$datediff = $date - $current;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want the number of minutes difference or only the minute part of the difference?

Comment: Need only number of minutes difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Comment: Its not proper solution

Comment: So you are saying that the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/365220/1213708 doesn't work for you - can you say why?

Comment: @WorldsHero show sample of input and result

Comment: `$current = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
 $date    = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item->dod_n)));`
Output 300 (Min)

Comment: @Nigel Ren Its thrownig error abs() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: @WorldsHero how subtraction of numbers results in two ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon for that:

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse('2019-10-04 07:01:00');
$date2 = Carbon::parse('2019-10-04 07:25:00');
echo $date2->diffInMinutes($date1);
```

Which here returns 24.
Is that what you need?