# do I calculate the percentage of two hours?

Tags: php, time

For example, there is a TV program between 18:30 and 19:30. It's 19:15 now. How do I get the time between these two times as a percentage? I need to find% for progress bar.

[image]

Comment: So are you asking how to do the math of percentages (not really a PHP question) or how to get the difference between two times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer on that question is actually rather poor.  The more upvoted answers are better.  (this doesn't take away from the fact that it could be selected as a possible duplicate)

Comment: I need to find% for progress bar. @PatrickQ

Comment: @ThuyRayn  That doesn't answer my question.  There are multiple steps involved.  What _specifically_ is giving you trouble?  And, importantly, _what have you tried_?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was the result I was looking for, thanks for your help.

```php
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');

$baslangic  = strtotime("2019-11-13 00:10:00");
$bitis      = strtotime("2019-11-13 01:00:00");
$simdi      = time();


if ($simdi < $baslangic) {
    $percentage = 0;
} else if ($simdi > $bitis) {
    $percentage = 100;
}else {
    $percentage = ($baslangic - $simdi) * 100 / ($baslangic - $bitis);
}

echo round($percentage,2);


?>
```

Comment: use  my code, i updated and added the percentage code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **DateTime** class:

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime('2014-09-18 21:00');
$now = new DateTime('2014-09-18 21:09');
$end = new DateTime('2014-09-18 21:36');

$total = $start->diff($end);
$totalTime = $total->format('%i');
$total = $start->diff($now);
$elapsedTime = $total->format('%i');

$percent = $elapsedTime / ($totalTime / 100);

echo $percent;
```

Which will output :

```
25
```

Which you can see in action here https://3v4l.org/Kjn6W

Learn about DateTime here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Learn about DateTimeInterval formats here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: I need to find% for progress bar.

Comment: OK, I will do your math too then 