# Difference of minute between two dateTime

Tags: php

I need to find the difference in minutes between these two dateTime in such format which is written. I get this error, please help:

Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/09/2020 01:00:19 AM) at position 0 (2):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('27/09/2020 01:00:19 AM');
                            $datetime2 = new DateTime('27/09/2020 01:00:19 AM');
                            $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                            echo $interval->format('%hh %im');
```

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/365214/12761193

Answer (score 1):

When parsing date formats, php follows [specific rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) :

If the date separator is `/`, then php will try to use either the American format `mm/dd/y` or the notation `YY/mm/dd`

You can specify the date/time format while creating the object using [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) :

```
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i:s a', '27/09/2020 01:00:19 AM');
$datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i:s a', '27/09/2020 01:00:19 AM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%hh %im');
```

This outputs :

```
0h 0m
```

[Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bfa5371a0433b891398595811113fe58579ff42d)

Comment: Perhaps add the why: PHP is considering dates with `/` as `m/d/y` and with `-` as `d-m-y` formatted. So `27/09/2020` is parsed as month = 27, day = 9, year = 2020. And there obviously isn't a month 29

Comment: while changing the datetime2 to 28/09/2020 01:00:19 AM then it does not give any result. Means while different dates

Comment: @user3153807 that's because you're only displaying the hours and minutes of the differences, not the days. This is a whole different question

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(str_replace('/','-','27/09/2020 01:00:19 AM'));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(str_replace('/','-','27/09/2020 01:00:19 AM'));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%hh %im');
```