# how to find the difference between 2 time formats using php

Tags: php

Ihave two variable format time

example :

```
$start = 16:00:00
$end   = 20:00:00

expected results  = 04:00
```

how to find the difference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    $dteStart = new DateTime("16:00:00");
    $dteEnd   = new DateTime("20:00:00");
    $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
    print $dteDiff->format("%H:%I"); // if you want to print seconds then use this: "%H:%I:%S" in format function
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Solution :

```
$start = '16:00:00';
$end   = '20:00:00';

$start = date("g:i", strtotime($start));
$end   = date("g:i", strtotime($end));

echo $start;// Print $start Variable
echo $end; // Print $end Variable
```

Comment: in model codeigniter

Comment: If you need extra help you can go with my profile page and contact me via Linkedin, Whatsapp and Email as well

Comment: @feriderpanzer Yes it's working on model codeigniter as well